# x-www-form-urlencoded request vs JSON reseed request - GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

If I make a JSON request:

http://mygeoserver.pt:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/TOPP:STREET.json

```
{
    "seedRequest": {
        "name":"SGM:SGM_RUA",
        "srs": {
            "number": "900913"
        },
        "zoomStart": 1,
        "zoomStop": 20,
        "format": "image/png",
        "type": "reseed",
        "threadCount": 4,
        "bounds": {
            "coords": {
                "double": [
                        "-851266.6436",
                        "4795638.2539",
                        "-850359.5510",
                        "4796040.7426"
                ]
            }
        },
        "parameters": {
            "entry": [
                {
                    "string": [
                        "STYLES",
                        "line"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The tiles won't refresh.. However, if I make a x-www-form-urlencoded request with same parameters it works.

http://mygeoserver.pt:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/TOPP:STREET?threadCount=01&type=reseed&gridSetId=EPSG%3A900913&tileFormat=image%2Fpng&zoomStart=19&zoomStop=19&parameter_STYLES=line&minX=-851266.6436&minY=4795638.2539%0A&maxX=-850359.5510&maxY=4796040.7426

Comment: what does the log file show?